# Misunderstanding ExecutorService - I think

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I want to start a group of 10 threads.  In my main program constructor I am using:

```
executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREADS);

Callable<String> poller;
for (int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) {
    Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Poller(0x3A, m_socket, ds_in, ds_out, socketLock));
    set.add(future);
}
```

For the call() method in class Poller I have :

```
public String call()
{
    // This has to be set here, otherwise all threads will have a name of "main".
    myID = Thread.currentThread().getName();

    boolean shutup_loop = true;
    do {
        System.out.println("Hey, I'm thread " + myID);
        System.out.println("Hey, I'm thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("thread " + myID + ": " + e);
        }

        // Do if you want the printing to all match up on one line
        synchronized (this) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = SendReceive(pollPacket);

            System.out.print(myID + ": ");
            if (baos != null) {
                printStuff(baos);
                System.out.println();
            }
            notify();
        }

    } while (shutup_loop);

    return "poller is finished";
}
```

These Poller threads are calling SendReceive(), part of the Poller class:

```
public synchronized ByteArrayOutputStream SendReceive(byte[] toSend)
{
    System.out.println("START");
    System.out.println("SendReceive()1 " + myID);
    System.out.println("SendReceive()2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    System.out.println("END");

    try {
        ds_out.write(toSend, 0, toSend.length);
        ds_out.flush();
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        System.out.println("thread " + myID + ": " + e);
    }

    try {
        m_socket.setSoTimeout(200);       // <-- might need tweaking
    }
    catch (java.net.SocketException e) {
        System.out.println("thread " + myID + ": " + e);
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    try {
        baos = getResponse(ds_in);
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        System.out.println("thread " + myID + ": " + e);
    }

    return baos;
}
```

Because this is a synchronized method I would expect the output to resemble:

```
START
SendReceive()1 pool-1-thread-1
SendReceive()2 pool-1-thread-1
END

START
SendReceive()1 pool-1-thread-2
SendReceive()2 pool-1-thread-2
END
```

Instead it is doing:

```
START
START
START
START
START
START
SendReceive()1 pool-1-thread-2
START
START
START
SendReceive()1 pool-1-thread-6
SendReceive()1 pool-1-thread-7
SendReceive()2 pool-1-thread-2
SendReceive()1 pool-1-thread-3
SendReceive()2 pool-1-thread-6
SendReceive()1 pool-1-thread-1
SendReceive()1 pool-1-thread-9
SendReceive()1 pool-1-thread-8
SendReceive()2 pool-1-thread-9
END
...
```

What gives?

Comment: Your question is about `synchronized`, not `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Your question is about `synchronized`, not `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Remove `synchronized` from `SendReceive` declaration (it's not doing anything anyway). Change `synchronized(this)` around the call to `SendReceive` to `synchronized(Poller.class)`. That'll make it work as intended. See assylias' answer to understand why.

Comment: What I'm really trying to do with these Poller threads is make them share a socket.  Every command has a send -> response so I want each thread to send its command and get its response.  I'll try these suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

`synchronized` uses `this` as a lock: in your case you have several `Poller` instances so each uses a different lock. To make it work you need a common lock:

- either make the method `static`
- or use a common `private static final Object lock = new Object();` and use `synchronized(lock) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

If what you are after is sharing the socket between pollers, you do not need to use an executor service. You need to serialize the use of the socket anyway, so you can just loop over the list of poll tasks and hand the current one the socket to work with.

On the other hand, if you really want to poll in parallel using the same socket, your network protocol should support that by allowing you to send a poll message without having to wait for a response to it; you would have multiple requests in flight. But I suspect that's a bigger and different problem that what you are trying to solve.

Comment: True, but I was doing it for the exercise of synchronization and resource locking.